# Core Text - How to know if text is Right to Left

Tags: ios, arabic, core-text

How can we know if the text of a CTRun is right to left?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have practical experience with `CTRun`, but from the documentation is seems that

```
 CTRunStatus CTRunGetStatus(CTRunRef run)
```

returns the information you need, the return value is a bitfield:

```
enum {
   kCTRunStatusNoStatus = 0,
   kCTRunStatusRightToLeft = (1 << 0),
   kCTRunStatusNonMonotonic = (1 << 1),
   kCTRunStatusHasNonIdentityMatrix = (1 << 2)
};
typedef uint32_t CTRunStatus;
```